# Знаете ли вы способы изменить соотношение сторон с 4:3 до 16:9 с помощью нейросетей

Tags: python, c#, vue.js, renpy

Есть желание сделать порт визуальной новеллы с неизвестного и забытого движка на относительно современный RenPy. Исходники у меня уже есть в наличии, однако они все в формате 4:3, хотелось бы их дорисовать до 16:9 любым образом, а потом улучшить изображение с помощью realsrGun. По понятным причинам не буду называть что за игра, однако после этого она уже будет в свободном доступе у всех желающих. Всё ради мододелов. Хотел использовать firefly, но мне не по карману. Kandinsky рисует наркоманию с карандашами. Поделитесь своими способами, по возможности и репами гитхаба - разберусь.

Comment: Берите Stable diffusion, ставьте нужную inpainting модель с нужной стилистикой, и вперед, без проблем дорисовывает то, что вам нужно.

Comment: Не проще орезать изображения сверху/снизу?

Comment: Резать изображение нельзя, тк будет выглядеть нелепо на fullHD экране да и в ней содержится нужная игровая информация.  EvgeniyZ, благодарю. Так и сделаю.  Если есть ещё способы, милости прошу писать сюда - это поможет другим людям, что буду заниматься модингом визуальных новелл.